# base64 encode null terminator

Tags: c++, null, base64, terminator

Hi I am currently trying to encode a string using the base64 encoding method in C++.

The string itself encodes fine however I would like to have an extra null character at the end of the decoded string (so the null character would also show up in the text file I want to save the decoded string into).

I am using this base64 code here -> http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html

I hope you can give me some advices what I can do here to make this possible (I tried already writing two null characters at the end of the string I am encoding but it seems as if the encoding method only reads to the first occurence of a null character).

Answer (score 1):

A cursory lookat the encoding function does not seem to show any special handling of NUL. And neither does the decoding function, are you sure the issue is not in the way that you test for NUL in the decoded string?

Comment: Actually I figured it out now, I had to explicitly append a null character at the end of the string, then the encode method processed that too (I guess it does encode every character). Previously I just had a char array where I added a null character in the final string but it seems that the encoding method wouldn't recieve the null character then.

Comment: @user1175111: The encoding method will encode as many characters as you ask for in the `length` argument (note that if you use `strlen` then it will stop counting in the first `NUL` but that if you *know* the size and pass it you will get what you need).